# How can I examine the CancelEventArgs from Application.Exit()?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WinForms app, I call `Application.Exit()` in certain circumstances.

`Application.Exit()` has an overload that looks like this:

`Application.Exit(CancelEventArgs e)`

And the documentation says that `e` "Returns whether any Form within the application cancelled the exit."

However, it's unclear to me how I could ever examine `e`.  The method returns void, and `e`is not defined as an out variable.  Am I supposed to be able to examine this?

Yes, I did look at other questions regarding Application.Exit(), but none of them address this.  They address handling the event, not calling the method.

Comment: Since `CancelEventArgs` is a mutable, reference type, it can be modified, but not reassigned, inside a method.

Comment: Strange kind of a paralysis.  Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know about paralysis. I don't actively try to fight the documentation.  In this case, I must just misunderstand where `out` or `ref` are required. I had no idea I could just throw my own objects into a method argument and expect them to be changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a `CancelEventArgs` variable and test its `Cancel` property after call to the `Application.Exit`:

```
CancelEventArgs e = new CancelEventArgs();
Application.Exit(e);
if (e.Cancel)
{
    // Cancelled
}
```

Comment: Weird. Shouldn't the Exit signature describe e as `ref` or `out`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can examine `e` is that `e` is a reference to the `CancelEventArgs` object you pass in the method call. A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you [pass a reference-type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/s6938f28.aspx), in this case a reference to a `CancelEventArgs` object, the called method is able to use the reference to access properties of the `CancelEventArgs` object, and it may for example set `e.Cancel` to `true`.

After the method call completes, the story is the same: `e` is still a reference to the `CancelEventArgs` object you passed, and you may now examine its properties to establish whether any have been changed by the called method.

*EDIT* I see from your comment it's not yet clear, so consider this: passing `e` as `ref` would mean the called method could change `e` to refer to a different `CancelEventArgs` object. It has nothing to do with whether it can set properties in the existing `CancelEventArgs` object.

Comment: Actually, I do understand the mechanics of the reference type. I;m just confused as to why `ref` or `out` is not required here? In my own code I cannot modify a passed reference type unless I declare it as ref or out in the signature of the method...

Comment: If it is a reference type you cannot change the reference but you can modify its properties.

Comment: @MikeCheel, yes. Cardinal Fang, I've edited my answer to add a further point clarifying this further.